# Enabling Sortable in jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, blockui

I want to disable jquery sortable on page load but not sure, someone direct me in right direction please,

In jquery I can do it like this   `$(".myList").sortable('disable');`

**Scenario**

I have a checkbox based on which I am enabling and disabling jquery sortable for a list, now I can use  `$(document).ready(function() {` and  `$(checkbox).change(function() {` to disable and enable dragging ***but I can't check it on page load in code behind as checkbox is getting its value from database on pageload.***

Comment: Can we see the code you *do* have?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist which code do you want to see

Comment: The code that loads the checkbox value, the current `change` event handler(s), etc. Everything you have that relates to what you're trying to do or the elements that are involved, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        if ($('#chcekbox).is(':checked')) {
        $(".myList").sortable('enable');
    } else {
        $(".myList").sortable('disable');
    }  
});
```